# how to create a log file in the working package in java?

Tags: java, struts

I have created a web project with struts as backend using eclipse ide.For every request i am creating a log file using java looging tool but the problem is the log file is getting created in the eclipse home folder. How do i create the log file in the working package and read in afterwards to display in jsp?

Comment: "_I have created a web project with struts as backend_" - might I ask why? Struts is antiquated. Even if this is a Struts2 project, it's still antiquated. Why create a new project with such arcane technology? Are you doing a form of software archaeology?

Comment: Struts on the back end is OK @boris

Comment: Really @RomanC? Is it _really_? Is it what you would chose for a new project? Over a newer web MVC framework? I doubt it. It's obsolete. And, again, if you are talking about Struts (as opposed to Struts2) you must be joking...

Comment: @Boris When I talking about Struts I mean the latest version of it. Currently it is 2.5.14. It's released recently. Because it's new I would recommend to use it for the new project.